# Question already has an answer - BUT not an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Specifically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171522/how-can-a-web-page-read-from-the-users-serial-port), but generally, any question closed as "already has an answer".

What if the question does not have an ***accepted*** answer?

Can it be closed just because it sounds similar to someone who might not have the technical knowledge to know if it is truly answered?

Instead of a Closure, shouldn't it be but a heavy hint to the OP? Only they can decide if it truly already has a answer, or if it the heavy-handed closer has not appreciated some differences (in the worst case), or if all of the "answers" are worthless.

Comment: That it is not accepted does in general not mean much.  Too many questioners around that don't bother or don't know how.  He never will.  But sure, that dup Q+A is pretty useless.  I hammered it back.

Comment: As on the main site, people seem to misunderstand the purpose of a downvote. It is meant to mean "I think that this question does not fulfil the criteria required", and not "I don't like your question. Of course, as on the main site, the downvoters don't bother to give an explanation (which could lead to rewording and to better questions in future) – all ***twelve** of them (or was it the usual one downvote attracting a bunch of drive-by “me too” downvoters, many of whom do not even bother to read the question?)

Comment: Unlike the main site, downvotes mean something rather different here. And even on the main site, they don't mean "this question does not fulfill the criteria required." That's the purpose of a *close* vote. A downvote means exactly what it says on the tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." This particular question shows no research effort (you are apparently unaware of most site policies and haven't bothered to look them up), and thus is not useful. And sigh. 11k rep and you still think comments should accompany downvotes. –1 just for that.

Comment: Hokey. Message recevied and understood. Thanks :-)      Btw, it is extremely rare for me to downvote and I **always** accompany with a comment. What's the point of the site, if not to help?

Comment: The point of this site is to build a library of knowledge, through high-quality answers to specific programming problems. Helping is nice, but it is a somewhat secondary goal. We aren't a help desk. If it is rare for you to downvote, you are very likely doing something wrong. In the tags I monitor, we get lots of low-quality questions that experts shouldn't waste their time looking at. Votes are how questions get rated. So either you follow tags where all the questions you look at are excellent, or you should be downvoting a lot more frequently. Remember that you aren't voting on *people*.

Comment: And what is the purpose of that "library of knowledge"? Knowledge for its own sake, or to help people? Good point about the downvotes. I do comment a lot to help improve the question, but rarely accompany it with a downvote. Maybe I ought to DV mor eoften

Comment: The critical question is *who* we're helping: the person who originally asked the question, or the thousands of people who will come looking for the answer later? Our primary focus is the latter.

Comment: Mien too, as it happens. But it is diificult to do that without helping the OP :-)

Comment: @Mawg When you lie to all of the future readers and fail to indicate that a post is problematic, you give them the false impression that the post is worth their time to read, when you know full well that it isn't.

Comment: If I comment, then I indicate that the post is problematic - and how it is so (which mere DV dows not). However, I take the point & will downvote more frequently in future (while continuing to explain why; I feel strongly that we have to educate. If we want to build that "library of knowledge", we have to tell people how to do so).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What if the question does not have an accepted answer?

A question needs to have either an accepted answer or an answer with a score of at least 1 to be considered "answered", which is what the duplicate closure uses as its criteria.

> Can it be closed just because it sounds similar to someone who might not have the techncial knowledge to know if it is truley answered?

Nope.  5 *experienced* users of the site (specifically, with 3k+ rep) could close it as a duplicate, partly because they're expected to be experienced enough to not vote to close a question they don't feel they understand.  It can only be closed by a single person if that person is a moderator (who we trust a *lot* to not close a question as a duplicate without good reason) or if the user has a gold badge in a tag the question is tagged with, in which case they're *not* someone without technical knowledge of the topic; they clearly *do* have *lots* of knowledge about the topic.

> Ought it not be not a close but a heavy hint to the OP? Only he can decide if it truly alreadty has a answer

No, they *aren't* the only one who can understand if the question is a duplicate.  An expert in the area, or five experienced users who are confident that they understand the question well enough, is more than sufficient.  If the question is so unclear that one couldn't determine what it's asking, then it should be closed as "unclear" of course.

> or of it the heavey handed closer has not appreciated some differences (in the worst case), or if all of the "answers" are worthless.

Then they're more than welcome to clarify the question to explain why the answers don't answer their question, and if those looking at the question feel that the author has adequately explained why the duplicate is not in fact a suitable duplicate, they can reopen the question in exactly the same way it was closed.